# onReceive() is not called in android broadcast-receiver for static broadcasts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am leaning Broadcastreceiver. I declared receiver in manifest file and have class MyBroadcastReceiver to receive intent but I am not able to receive any intent. The onRecive() function is never called for example when Aeroplane mode is changed or earphone is plugged-in or plugged-out. Following is code for manifest.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadCastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Following is code for BroadCastReceiver class.

```
public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Action: " + intent.getAction() + "\n");
    sb.append("URI: " + intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME).toString() + "\n");
    String log = sb.toString();
    Log.d(TAG, log);
    Toast.makeText(context, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: need few more logic like how you are initiating service

Comment: @AravindV I don't have any service I just wants to receive broadcast for when Aeroplane mode is changed or earphone is plugged-in or plugged-out.

Answer (score 1):

If your App targets 8.0 or higher. You can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in the manifest and `android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE` is an implicit broadcast. For more details [read this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

As a work around, you can still register dynamically using `Context.registerReceiver()` at runtime for both implicit and explicit broadcast. But your app needs to be alive to receive it.